# Failed inserting record into table_sensor_log table - Syntax error - failed inserting record to table - 42000

Tags: python, mysql, syntax

Im trying to take readings from my BME280 sensor and write them as a line in a Mysql Database using a python script. I'm sure the answer is pretty simple, however I've been banging my head against a wall for ages about this.

Current error is: Failed inserting record into table_sensor_log table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '09:29:03.708933,3fa924c8-73b1-4986-a9bc-f13fdc15163f,25.7461863119)' at line 2
MySQL connection is closed

I am getting a correct reading off my sensor.

Pretty much tried everything I can think of - have reformulated the code multiple times.

```py
import smbus2
import bme280

port = 1
address = 0x76
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)

calibration_params = bme280.load_calibration_params(bus, address)

# the sample method will take a single reading and return a
# compensated_reading object
data = bme280.sample(bus, address, calibration_params)

# the compensated_reading class has the following attributes
timest = data.timestamp
id = data.id
temperature = data.temperature

# there is a handy string representation too
print(data)
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
   connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='sensor_log',
# the compensated_reading class has the following attributes
timest = data.timestamp
id = data.id
temperature = data.temperature

# there is a handy string representation too
print(data)
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
   connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='sensor_log',
                             user='superadmin',
                             password='Chillipo3')
   sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO `table_sensor_log`
                          (`timestamp`, `sensor_id`, `sensor_value`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);""" % (timest,id,temperature,)
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
   connection.commit()
   print ("Record inserted successfully into table_sensor_log table")
except mysql.connector.Error as error :
    connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
    print("Failed inserting record into table_sensor_log table {}".format(error))
finally:
    #closing database connection.
```

The readings are coming out ok - I left them in to prove that my sensor has no issues.

compensated_reading(id=3fa924c8-73b1-4986-a9bc-f13fdc15163f, timestamp=2019-07-27 09:29:03.708933, temp=25.746 °C, pressure=1009.16 hPa, humidity=55.00 % rH)
Failed inserting record into table_sensor_log table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '09:29:03.708933,3fa924c8-73b1-4986-a9bc-f13fdc15163f,25.7461863119)' at line 2
MySQL connection is closed
2019-07-27 09:29:03.708933

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to format the query yourself using python formatting. [`execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) takes a second parameter which is the variables that you would like to insert into your query

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO `table_sensor_log`
        (`timestamp`, `sensor_id`, `sensor_value`)
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s);
""", [timest,id,temperature])
```

The database driver will take care of escaping/quoting the variables you pass

Comment: Ok - this is a definite improvement - however, I'm getting an issue elsewhere now.

Failed inserting record into table_sensor_log table Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'uuid' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: I presume I need to convert the values to a string but I'm not sure how at present.

Comment: Cracked it.

`code`
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO `table_sensor_log`
        (`timestamp`, `sensor_id`, `sensor_value`)
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s);
""", [str(timest),str(id),str(temperature)])